# Reading scripture in front of a donkey

Tags: idiom-requests, proverb-requests

Reading scripture in front of a donkey.  The country of origin of this proverb is Afghanistan (as far as I know) but we also have exactly the same idiom, identical in meaning, in our native language - the gospel was being read in front of (above the head of) a wolf but he was howling - let me go, the sheep are fleeing!

We use this expression when we want to emphasize that talking to a person (getting through his/her thick skull) is a futile endeavor; it's useless. I had been talking about the dangers of tobacco to him for an hour or so, when he took out a pack of cigarettes and started smoking.

I would like to know whether there is an equivalent expression in English, germane to the above-mentioned one?

Comment: What is 'our native language'? Which gospel (chapter and verse) are you referring to?

Comment: My native language is Georgian,  we`re Orthodox Christians and Afghans are Muslims, as you may know. In my understanding, in both cases, as to scripture or gospel, either one is used as an equivalent of an edifying book, which possesses the most important moral qualities and values. They do not refer to any particular verse or chapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find your answer in the link given in the comment section by Edwin Ashworth, but if you like more idioms to consider, then I suggest:

**(like) water off a duck's back**.

> Criticisms of or warnings to a particular person that have no effect on that person. [(Cambridge)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/like-water-off-a-duck-s-back)
>
> - *I've told him that he's heading for trouble, but he doesn't listen - it's just water off a duck's back*.

Here is another example from Merriam Webster:

> - He tried to convince her to take the job, but his advice was like water off a duck's back.

**Be banging, etc. your head against a brick wall**.

> To try to do something that is very difficult or impossible to achieve and therefore causes you to feel annoyed. [(Cambridge)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/like-water-off-a-duck-s-back)
>
> - *I keep asking her not to park there but it's like banging your head against a brick wall*.

Comment: Neither or these applies to the OP’s scenario in my opinion. “Water off a duck’s back” is usually used to show that a person is unaffected/undisturbed by something:  “This obstacle would deter a lesser man, but to John it was like water off a duck’s back.”

Comment: What? Compare the example given by the OP "*I had been talking about the dangers of tobacco to him for an hour or so, when he took out a pack of cigarettes and started smoking.*" with the example from Cambridge dictionary; and in my opinion, they are the same.

Comment: As I have already mentioned in my original comment, we use this expression, when we want to underline the fact that one refuses to accept a piece of useful advice and moreover, does exactly the opposite.

Comment: @Gio Let me rephrase your example, and then you'll see if they are the same or not. *"I had been talking to him about not to park there for an hour or so, when he parked his car just a minute later in front of me and took out a pack of cigarettes and started smoking, and it was like I had been banging my head against a brick wall"*  or *".... but what I said was like water off a duck's back."*

Comment: like water off a duck's back - primarily refers to one`s inability to accept criticism or take  insults, whereas the expressions presented in my original comment refer to one`s refusal to accept a piece of useful advice. Other than that, these two are more or less alike.

Comment: @Gio Weren't you warning him about the danger of smoking? I added another example from Merriam Webster. *"He tried to convince her to take the job, but his **advice** was like water off a duck's back."*

Comment: I think the OP wants something more apropos to the *speaker*'s frustration ... which this answer notes in its opening sentence. (*+1, particularly for the second suggestion*)

Answer (score 2):

Talking to a brick wall
[thefreedictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/talk+to+a+brick+wall)

> If talking to someone is like talking to a brick wall, the person you
>   are speaking to does not listen: I've tried to discuss my feelings
>   with her, but it's like talking to a brick wall.
>  [Cambridge
>   Advanced Learner’s Dictionary & Thesaurus](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-like-talking-to-a-brick-wall)

Depending on your needs, the following may be appropriate: "in one ear and out the other."

> If you say that something goes in one ear and out the other, you mean
>   that someone pays no attention to it, or forgets about it immediately.
>   
>  [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-one-ear-and-out-the-other)